# Facial recognition using open cv and visual studio

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on my BE project on facial recognition and have been referring [this](http://code.google.com/p/visual-control/wiki/Compiling) for understanding and trying out the codes.

However, when I compile the codes and set paths as given in the tutorial, I get the following error:

```
1   IntelliSense: constant "cv::CascadeClassifier::DO_CANNY_PRUNING" (declared at line 411 of "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp") is inaccessible    c:\users\mugdha\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\facial_rec_final\facial_rec_final\codes project\facedetector.cpp  127 27  visualcontrol
```

I've included the objdetect.hpp file in the path
Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

it's :

```
CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING
```

in opencv2.4.x, and

```
cv::CASCADE_DO_CANNY_PRUNING
```

in opencv3.0

(oh, and please don't use opencv2.1 that's like 4 years old.)